# Mongoose data base connection/disconnection. Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to close the connection of mongoDB using NodeJS?

```
    mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'));
    this.db = mongoose.connection;
   db.once('open', function () {console.log('>>db opened');});//this doesn't call!
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({name:String});
    var User = mongoose.model(dbUserName, schema);
    mongoose.disconnect(function () {console.log('db closed');});//neither line line works
    this.db.close(function () {console.log('db closed');});//nor this line!
```

I don't know how to close db connections. The last tow lines doesn't work! If I write again:

```
mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'));
```

the log will say

> Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
>   How to fix this essue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. My be It will help to somebody.
In my case I changed

```
 mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'));
```

this.db = mongoose.connection;
into this

```
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');
```

In this case all callbackes works (correctly). I don't know bug this or feature but now it works. There is no enough documentation...